# Axios call to different origin does not work only when the Nuxt.js + Capacitor app is in production as apk

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, nuxt.js, capacitor

I'm building a Nuxt.js + Capacitor by Ionic app and I created the apk version.
It's a static app (`target: 'static'`) with no server side rendering (`ssr: false`).

I need to make two remote calls to different endpoints (so CORS call) via `axios` so I did something like:

```js
const results = await this.$axios(
  {
    url: 'books',
    method: 'get',
    baseURL: 'https://server1.custom.com/'
  },
);
```

but I get an error: `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://server.custom.com/books' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.`

So I defined a `proxy` in `nuxt.config.js`:

```
proxy: {
  '/api1/': {
    target: 'https://server1.custom.com/',
    pathRewrite: { '^/api1/': '' },
  },
  '/api2/': {
    target: 'https://server2.custom.com/',
    pathRewrite: { '^/api2/': '' },
  },
}
```

and using `baseURL: '/api1/',` in axios makes the call to just work fine.
The final request becomes `http://localhost:3000/api1/books`.

**It works while in `dev` mode using Chrome v110.**

At that point I build the final nuxt app by running:

```bash
nuxt build
nuxt generate
npx cap copy
npx cap open android
```

I generate the apk in Android Studio and then I open it on my Android phone.
When it's on the phone the **remote calls do not work anymore and I see a `404` axios error while calling `/api1/`** (the error shows `baseURL: "/api1/"`, `get` method and `"url": "books"`).

I noticed that the main difference in the host location between dev and phone is that it works when running on `http://localhost:3000` while it's not when on phone (`window.location.origin` shows `http://localhost` when it's running as apk on the phone). I don't know whether that matters or not!

Can you tell what the issue is here and how to solve it?

Thanks

Comment: localhost is being seen on your machine but it isn't available on your mobile.. you need to server your backend externally so it serves from ip instead of localhost and that will still be a solution just in testing.. to solve this everywhere, instead of using axios, you need to use native http calls `https://ionicframework.com/docs/v5/native/http`.. or if you need to keep working on axios, then you need to allow cors in your backend (Nuxt.js) which is allowing headers (allow-access-origin: *) which is something i don't do personally.. i usally use native http calls which is safer...

Comment: thanks for your comment. Is there a version of https://ionicframework.com/docs/v5/native/http for vue?

Comment: not sure, but this version should work with ionic-angular, ionic-vue, and ionic-react.. so mostly capacitor should hold the logic to work from your selected framework to native sdks.. but i ain't familiar with ionic-vue or ionic-react so can't give a guaranteed answer... try it and would be great if u send if it worked or not..